# AWS Secret Manager `ParamValidationError`: `"SecretID", must be one of: SecretId, VersionId, VersionStage`

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-secrets-manager

I am having a problem with accessing a secret from Secret Manager in a lambda function.

Here is the relevant code:

```
import boto3

session = boto3.session.Session()
secretsmanager = session.client(service_name="secretsmanager")

get_secret_value_response = secretsmanager.get_secret_value(
    SecretID="arn:aws:secretsmanager:SECRETNAME"
)
secret = get_secret_value_response["SecretString"]
```

The error message, however, is confusing. Neither I found mentions of it elsewhere.

```
[ERROR] ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Missing required parameter in input: "SecretId"
Unknown parameter in input: "SecretID", must be one of: SecretId, VersionId, VersionStage
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/notification_parser.py", line 14, in handler
    get_secret_value_response = secretsmanager.get_secret_value(
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 530, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 919, in _make_api_call
    request_dict = self._convert_to_request_dict(
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 990, in _convert_to_request_dict
    request_dict = self._serializer.serialize_to_request(
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/validate.py", line 381, in serialize_to_request
    raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())
```

The [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/secretsmanager/client/get_secret_value.html#get-secret-value) shows a string value, so I am confused.

Any ideas where I could go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You error is clear which is the name of the `SecretID` and `SecretId`. You named it incorrectly.

Just change the variable name to `SecretId` instead of `SecretID` the last letter should be lowercase.

But if you want here is the example how to use it

```py
import boto3


SECRET_ARN = "YOUR_SECRET_ARN"
secret_manager = boto3.client('secretsmanager')

response = secret_manager.get_secret_value(
    SecretId=SECRET_ARN
)

# this might be a json string so you might need to parse it
# to parse it you can use json.loads(response['SecretString'])
print('Secret: ' + response['SecretString'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code to get a secret using Python.

```
# snippet-start:[python.example_code.secrets-manager.GetSecretValue]
    def get_value(self, stage=None):
        """
        Gets the value of a secret.

        :param stage: The stage of the secret to retrieve. If this is None, the
                      current stage is retrieved.
        :return: The value of the secret. When the secret is a string, the value is
                 contained in the `SecretString` field. When the secret is bytes,
                 it is contained in the `SecretBinary` field.
        """
        if self.name is None:
            raise ValueError

        try:
            kwargs = {'SecretId': self.name}
            if stage is not None:
                kwargs['VersionStage'] = stage
            response = self.secretsmanager_client.get_secret_value(**kwargs)
            logger.info("Got value for secret %s.", self.name)
        except ClientError:
            logger.exception("Couldn't get value for secret %s.", self.name)
            raise
        else:
            return response
# snippet-end:[python.example_code.secrets-manager.GetSecretValue]
```